# How would one go about integrating $x^x$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

So I have been trying to solve $\int x^x dx$ as a challenge from one of my friends. Before anyone says it, I recognize that the equation has no *closed* solutions. I have been trying to integrate by using series. I tried recognizing that $x^x = e^{xln(x)}$ to express the function as a Taylor series to integrate that. Yet I end up with a particularly nasty double sum: $\sum_{m=0} ^\infty \sum_{n=1} ^\infty \frac{1}{m!} \left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}x(x-1)^n\right)^m$. I tried to change the double sum to a single sum, but I can't recall how. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you just use one Taylor sum? $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(x\ln(x))^{n}}{n!}$ Apologies if you've already gone past this point.

Comment: You're probably better off trying to integrate $x^n (\log{x})^n$ directly: you can get $x^n$ times a polynomial in $\log{x}$ using integration by parts.

Comment: @Tdonut I think I could, but then I end up with the problem of integrating xln(x), which seems less than ideal, especially since the product is raised to a power.

Comment: @Chappers I don't understand what you mean by getting $x^n$ times a polynomial in log(x). Unless you're referring to using a Taylor series there and then distributing the x?

Comment: @RobMerrell I think, $\int x\ln (x) dx=\frac 12 x^{2}\ln(x)+\int\frac 12x^{2}\frac 1xdx=\frac 12 x^{2}\ln(x)+\frac{x^{2}}{4}$

Comment: @Tdonut But doesn't the fact that the entire thing is to the n power (considering it is a sum) change that?

Comment: Yes it does. I thought you had that figured out :). I don't know how you would go about integrating it, although there must be a way.

Comment: Can you solve after this? It might just be more complicated. $\int x^{n}(\ln x)^{n}dx = \frac {x^{n+1}}{n+1}(\ln x)^{n}+\int x^{n}\frac{n(\ln x)^{n-1}}{x}dx$

Comment: @RobMerrell: Shouldn't the sum over $n$ be _inside_ the $m$th power? (Unfortunately, that means you don't even have a double sum yet....)

Comment: See also [Sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream).

Answer (score 2):

(Too long for a comment)

We know that
$$ ((\log{x})^k)' = \frac{k}{x}(\log{x})^{k-1}, $$
so we can use integration by parts as follows: write
$$ I(m,n) \int x^m (\log{x})^n \, dx, $$
so
$$ I(m,n) = \frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1} (\log{x})^{n} - \frac{n}{m+1}\int x^{m} (\log{x})^{n-1} \, dx = \frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1} (\log{x})^{n} - \frac{n}{m+1}I(m,n-1). $$
It is clear that $I(m,0)=\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}$, so $I(m,n)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $\log{x}$, multiplied by $x^{m+1}$, for any nonnegative integer $n$.

Comment: Just checking: Doesn't the OP want to integrate $x^{x} = e^{x \log x}$ rather than $x \log x$...?

Comment: @user86418 Yes, and they wrote it as $e^{x\log{x}}$ and expanded the exponential in a power series in $x\log{x}$. This is in response to the discussion in the comments about integrating term-by-term.

Comment: Ah, I see; my apology. :)